# How to set the value of open_basedir?

Tags: php, linux, apache

The document root for my website is `/data/home/htdocs`.

In my vps `php.ini` there is  a line `open_basedir= /data/home` under which, there is this line:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

Now, there is a problem. My site can't upload any image, but when I comment `open_basedir= /data/home` this line, it can upload the image.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

According to [man](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir),

> When a script tries to open a file with, for example, fopen() or gzopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to open it.

You are uploading files in `/tmp`, but your `open_basedir` is set to all folders inside `/data/home`, so you don't have access to '/tmp' to write files.

So, you have to modify `upload_tmp_dir` to be somewhere inside `/data/home`